# jQuery UI Spinner

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI spinner [jQuery UI Spinner](https://jqueryui.com/spinner/#decimal)and I would like to get rid of the comma number format, my code is as following :

```
$( "#tank_capacity" ).spinner({
  min: 0.00,
  step: 0.01,
  numberFormat: "n"
});
```

When the spinner reaches 1000.01 it formats the number to : 1,000.01 I want it to always stay like 1000.01 is there a way to do it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you provide more info about your enviroment? I'd tested it on jsfiddle on chrome and works fine (1000.xx instead of 1,000.xx), se working example below, almost here I get the format that you are pointing to.

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
   step: 0.01,
   numberFormat: "n"
  });  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
 <label for="spinner">Decimal spinner:</label>
 <input id="spinner" name="spinner" value="999.98">
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You pointed me to my code an I found that I had this script loaded too that makes the formating :                             <script src="globalize.js"></script> I removed it and it is working like your code. Thanks again